# How do I use SharePoint Rest API in C# .NET Framework using Client ID and Client Secret?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there any way to authenticate an application with SharePoint rest API like Graph API using Client ID and Client Secret? I wanna use SharePoint rest API in my console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

In Azure Active Directory I have configured permissions for SharePoint API.
[image]

In my code I have scopes defined this way:

```
var scopes = new [] {"https://<tenantName>.sharepoint.com/allsites.manage"};

var clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create($"{clientId}")
            .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
            .WithClientSecret($"{clientSecret}").Build();

// acquire a token for the app
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
    result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                             .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
...
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, It returns an exception Invalid Scope. How to overcome this exception and How to create a request to get all sites in my tenant? Need your help @user2250152